# Laravel Reflection Exception Class Does Not Exist

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to troubleshoot a Laravel issue by clearing cache and dump auto load and updating composer.json file and now when I navigate to my server I get all of [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86bEH.png). The error before was boostrap cache had wrong permissios so I did `sudo chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache` to fix that issue but now I have a bunch of other errors.

UPDATE: route list is as follows: [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6ulJ.png)

Comment: Put the code related to that error.

Comment: there is no code related to this issue since I did not make any code changes for this error, it is based on the laravel configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This command worked on my issue:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

In the Laravel doc it says that laravel by default is configured to use file cache driver which stores cached objects in filesystem, so it is necessary to recache filesystem. this is because after clearing the cache laravel doesn't know of which view to fetch from cache although you have cleared it. so after `config:cache` it tells to laravel to recache the new views and to available it to show. Hope it will help.

Comment: I used that command on my computer and then pushed it to server and I still get the same error.

Comment: What does `php artisan route:list` show you on local machine?

Comment: have you checked you .env file, there might be several options for this issue 1- check your .env file and if there would be any space in the variable like **API KEY** instead of **API_KEY** , other option is that you might have missing a comma in config/app in the providers array.

Comment: Also run `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Thank you @NaveedAli, composer update, and composer dump-autoload worked for me.

Comment: @Hriju that's great, if it helps you then upvote it so it help others too.

Answer (score 1):

Change mode to `777` and after that run commands: `php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache && php artisan cache:clear`. Then if `bootstrap/cache/config.php` was not deleted then delete it also and try again.

It will work fine.